# spark predicate push down is not working with phoenix hbase table

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hbase, apache-phoenix

I am working on spark-hive-hbase integration.Here phoenix hbase table am using for the integration.

```
Phoenix : **apache-phoenix-4.14**
HBase   : **hbase-1.4**
spark   : **spark-2.3**
hive    : **1.2.1**
```

I am using spark thrift server and accessing the table using **jdbc.**

Almost all basic features which i tested is working fine. but when i submit a query from spark **with where condition it's submitted to phoenix with out where condition** and all filtering happening in the spark side.

If the table has billions of data we can't go with this.

**example:**

```
Input-query: select * from hive_hbase where rowid=0;

Query-submitted: PhoenixQueryBuilder: Input query : select /*+ NO_CACHE  */ "rowid","load_date","cluster_id","status" from hive_hbase
```

is it a bug?
Please suggest if there is any way to force the query to submit with where condition(filter) (with jdbc only).

Thanks & Regards
Rahul

Answer (score 0):

The above-mentioned behavior is not a bug rather a feature of spark, which will make sure that filter is not happening on the DB side rather it is done at spark's end, which therefore ensures performance for a non-rowkey filter and execution can be finished fast. If you still want to push the predicates for all intents and purposes you can use phoenix-spark or rather edit the predicate pushdown code of spark on your own. Below are links for your reference

1. https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/87551/predicate-pushdown-support-in-hortonworks-hbase-co.html
2. http://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-sql/predicate-pushdown-spark-sql/read

Comment: dear sandeep if i edit the code myself it's hard to handle all the cases eg: union. it would be  better if some fix/improvements comes from spark/phoenix side.

Comment: Both links in this answer mention predicate pushdown, which does do filtering on the DB side not in Spark.  That seems to contradict the rest of what is written in this answer.